# two rows of three <li>- how to have each row top aligned

Tags: css, css-float, alignment, html-lists

I have a menu section on a website that consists of 2 rows with 3 items in each row. I managed to have the top row top aligned by using `float:left`, but am unsure of how to top align the bottom row. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="services">
    <div class="banner-image">
    <img src="img/large.jpg" alt="BodywoRx room" />
    </div><!-- end banner-image -->
    <h2>We have a massage that fits YOU.</h2>
    <div id="service-list">
    <div class="service">
        <h3>Coffee Break $25:</h3><p>15 minute chair massage that focuses on the shoulders, neck, arms, wrists and hands.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
        <h3>Lunch Break $40:</h3><p>30 minute table massage that focuses on the shoulders, neck, and lower back.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
        <h3>Lympathic Drainage $50:</h3><p>Session provides congestion relief for the face, throat, and chest.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
            <h3>Bliss $60:</h3><p>60 minute full body massage using light to medium pressure.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
        <h3>Deep Tissue $80:</h3><p>60 minute full body massage using deep pressure.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
        <h3>Correction $95:</h3><p>Session focuses on centering the body and finding and relieving dysfunction that is causing chronic pain and discomfort.</p>
    </div>
    </div><!-- end service-list -->



#services {
    width: 960px;
}

#services .banner-image {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#services h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#services #service-list {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.service {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 40px;
    width: 265px;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to have 6 items in one row?  Where are these <li>'s that you said?

Comment: You want 2 rows of `.service` items with 3 `.service` items in each row?  And you need the text in the `.service` item to be top aligned?  Try using `.service { vertical-align:top; }` in

Comment: @zen, you're right i copy/pasted the old code i was using. i'll replace. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "top align" you mean keep the second row starting in the same place vertically (ie the tops all line up) simply add `height:100px;` to your `.service` styles